# Domain of $f(x, y, z) = \ln(z - y) + yx \cdot \sin z$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

Why would the domain of the function

$f(x, y, z) =  \ln(z - y) + yx \cdot \sin z$

be $z - y > 0$

How does that take into account the domain of $\sin(z)$ ? Why would it not be $z > y >= 1$ ?

Comment: What do you think the domain of $\sin z$ is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the domain of a function, you can look at the domain of its components.

The $\log$ function can only take positive values. The product $xy$ can take any two values. The $\sin$ function can take any value — remember, $\sin(z)$ takes in a distance $z$ around the unit circle (a distance which can be any number: positive, negative, zero) and returns a ratio between -1 and 1.

Because the only genuine restriction we have comes from the $\log{(z-y)}$ component, the only restriction for the overall function $f(x,y,z)$ to be well-defined is that this argument $z-y$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have,

$$f= g_1(x,y,z)+ g_2(x,y,z)$$

i.e $\textit{dom}(f) = \bigcap_{j=1}^2 \textit{dom}(g_j(x,y,z))$ and remember the domain is just were each function has a definition.

Comment: I think you mean $\bigcap$.